# Carbon converts 12:00 to wrong time

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

It seems Carbon converts 12:00 (24:00) vice versa when the format is "H a":

```
$time = Carbon::createFromFormat("H a", "12 AM")->toTimeString(); // "00:00:00"
$time = Carbon::createFromFormat("H a", "12 PM")->toTimeString(); // "12:00:00"
```

Why it does that and is there any way to avoid this or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Wrong? According to [which convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight)? If you want to be unambiguous, just avoid am/pm formats.

Comment: Try it with 11:59 instead. 12 is not a good number to test using am/pm times

Comment: @Amadan Oh, all the time I thought that 12 AM = 12:00, 12 PM = 00:00, so it's actually working right. Thanks, my life will never be the same ))

Comment: It is, in Japan. In USA, it doesn't make sense (12PM is noon, continuing numbering from the morning, and taking PM from afternoon) but it is what it is. 24-hour clocks ftw.